# How to pass numpy array to Cython function correctly and fastly?

Tags: python, c++11, cython

I started from the example code for testing, but calling function is way too slow.
Here are codes.
The first cout in Rectangle.cpp comes out about 20 seconds after run python code.
I guess that it copying memory when the NumPy data is passing to c++ function.
Can anyone explain the problem? and what I should study and how to solve this problem.

Rectangle.cpp

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > Rectangle::ret_mat(std::vector< std::vector<double>> sv, std::vector<std::vector<double>> sv2, std::vector<double> sv3)
{
    std::cout <<"WHYWHY? " << std::endl;
    start = clock();
    int svrows = sv.size();
    int svcols = sv[0].size();

    std::vector< std::vector<double> > tot;
    tot.resize(svrows, std::vector<double> (svcols, -1));

    int svrows2 = sv2.size();
    int svcols2 = sv2[0].size();

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> tot2;
    tot2.resize(svrows2, std::vector<double> (svcols2, -1));

    position_x = sv3.at(0);
    position_y = sv3.at(1);
    position_z = sv3.at(2);
}
```

Rect.pyx

```
cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.thisptr = new Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr
    def getLength(self):
        return self.thisptr.getLength()
    def getHeight(self):
        return self.thisptr.getHeight()
    def getArea(self):
        return self.thisptr.getArea()
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.thisptr.move(dx, dy)
    def sum_vec(self, sv):
        return self.thisptr.sum_vec(sv)
    def sum_mat(self, sv):
        return self.thisptr.sum_mat(sv)
    def sum_mat_ref(self, sv):
        return self.thisptr.sum_mat_ref(sv)
    def ret_mat(self, sv, sv2, sv3):
        return self.thisptr.ret_mat(sv, sv2, sv3)
```

python_test.py
size of the list7 NumPy array is about 6000000 ~ 8000000

```
list7 = np.load('~/npy/map.npy') # map
list8 = np.load('~/npy/v0.1_np1000000_w10/000051/scenario3_ori_scan000051.npy') # scan
list9 = np.load('~/npy/v0.1_np1000000_w10/000051/scenario3_ori_odom000051.npy') # odom
Result = R1.ret_mat(list7,list8,list9)
```

Comment: You are passing the function arguments by value, I think you probably want to pass it by reference instead, i.e. `std::vector< std::vector<double>>& sv` and similarly for `sv2` and `sv3`.

Comment: Passing by reference won't help much. The real issue is that the conversion from Numpy array to vector of vector is a slow, element-by-element copy. Also vector of vector is an awful data structure for representing a matrix